# Get field instance from abstract class

Tags: java, reflection

Given, for example, a class like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractSomething {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Somefield, AnotherField> myAttribute;
}
```

how can I get an instance of `myAttribute` via reflection. There are no implementing classes for `AbstractSomething`.

---

**EDIT**

No, we need an instance of the `SingularAttribute<T, S>`. And the reason we need to use reflection is becuase these classes are generated and passed into our method as a `Class` object. We have no way no know which `AbstractSomething` we are receiving. There are quite a few of them.

---

**EDIT 2**

Found out what the issue was. When a Hibernate context is present in the application, the interfaces on the abstract class are replaced with their implementation counterparts when accessing them.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want the `Field` instance for the `myAttribute` field from the class `AbstractSomething`?

Comment: Why do you need to get it via reflection? What information do you have? What have you tried, and what happened? We need more information.

Comment: This is a `static` field, there aren't many `myAttribute`, only one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - No thats only to show the concept. Each of the `AbstractSomething` classes have 10+ fields. Please see my edit.

Comment: And all of them have a field called `myAttribute`? Do you know if it will be initialized?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - No, they all have different names. That is why we are going through them and instantiating the fields. The class itself is abstract with no implementation, so it cannot be instantiated. Is is a meta class generated from a JEE entity by hibernate with the `@StaticMetamodel` annotation.

Comment: @NicoHuysamen There's still something missing here. It doesn't matter if you have an implementation or not if it's a `static` field.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - O yes sorry, SingularAttribute<T, S> is an interface :(

Comment: Let's clarify. You want to get the value of a `static` field of type `SingularAttribute` of some given `Class`. That value will be `null` unless it has been initialized.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Exactly. I had it working previously by calling `field.get(field)` (where field is a reference to the `Field` variable containing `myAttribute`). Trying to figure out what the other devs changed to break it.

Answer (score 3):

No big deal actually, you can do something like this:

```
Field field = AbstractSomething.class.getField("myAttribute")
```

And then you can access it by invoking `field.get(null)` and `field.set(null, value)`

The real question is WHY do you want to use reflection, but I guess you have your reasons.

**EDIT:**

If you have a Class instance in before hand (lets call it classInstance) then you can do

```
Field field = classInstance.getField("myAttribute")
```

to get the Field that reificates the field you are looking for... and if you want all fields just invoke the `getFields` method.

You don't really need a concrete implementation nor an instance of the reificated class in question in order to access the static fields.

Comment: So you dont know "AbstractSomething" but you have a Class instance... can't you just do classInstance.getField("myAttribute") then?

Comment: `field.get(null)` was what I was looking for. Was not intuitive to pass in `null` when referencing an abstract class (interface in my case with no implementing class) so glad I found this.

Answer (score 0):

No need for reflection. The field belongs to the *class*, and no matter how many subclasses there are, there is only *one* instance of the `AbstractSomething` class, so just:

```
SingularAttribute<Somefield, AnotherField> attr = AbstractSomething.myAttribute;
```

Comment: They don't seem to have access to the `AbstractSomething` types at compile time.

Comment: OK then, what do you know? The name of the field? The type? The modifiers (static, protected, etc)? Something else?